# Problems Using the right Version of Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos

I have Python version 3.9.6 installed.

When I do:

```
python -V
```

in the Terminal or run a simple script:

```
import os
sys print(sys.version)
```

it shows 3.9.6, but when I have the database Panorama call to the same script it always comes up with 2.7.10.

Tried each of the following paths and it still shows Python 2:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/python
#!/usr/bin/python
#!/usr/local/bin/python
```

Could it be something to do with the shell or env?

Thanks

Comment: You should use python3 instead python.

Comment: How are you calling Python from Panorama? What is the value of your `PATH` variable when it works correctly vs. when it doesn't?

Comment: In your Terminal, when you type `which python`, what do you get ?

Comment: It python or python3 return the same result no matter where it is run and show up as  python 3.9.6.

 which python returns: "/usr/local/bin/python"
.

As for the path in Panorama I tried ALL of the paths as I already mentioned and none of them work. It all works fine when run in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Had to have Panorama call Applescript which then ran it as a shell script. Runs fine now.

Thanks